# Error configuring Gitlab CI in Maven project (SpringBoot)

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm actually doing my first project, which uses Gitlab CI & Pipelines. I'd would like to create a stage which will build the application (and then a test), I tried to follow this tutorial: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/artifactory_and_gitlab/ but actually I have an error when the pipeline is executed.

The error that I can't handle is :

**ERROR :**

```html
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for GoStyle:GoStyle:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:pom:2.1.7.RELEASE from/to UK (http://uk.maven.org/maven2):
Transfer failed for http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.1.7.RELEASE.pom 501 HTTPS Required and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 24, column 13
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml :**

```html
image: maven:latest

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s settings.xml --batch-mode"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile
```

**pom.xml :**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>GoStyle</groupId>
    <artifactId>GoStyle</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>



</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the repository

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```